# Unable to install any package from Pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my personal laptop. I installed pip for Python3.8 using the command

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

However, everytime I try to install any package using

```
pip3 install pandas
```

I am getting this error

```
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
> object at 0x7f3122821460>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pandas/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
> object at 0x7f3122821460>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pandas/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
> object at 0x7f3122821460>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pandas/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
> object at 0x7f3122821460>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pandas/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
> object at 0x7f3122821460>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pandas/
```

I have tried all solutions present online. Nothing is working. I am not connected through any proxy server and the internet connection is working perfectly

Comment: maybe it is worth trying `python3 -m pip install`

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator This is giving the same error as I've mentioned above.

Comment: Are you using the `HTTP_PROXY` or `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables? You can check this with `env | grep HTTP`. Pip will try to use these if they are set.

Comment: @RoadRunner No, I'm not.

Comment: @RitikaNandi Interesting. Have you tried doing a manual install?

Comment: A manual installation of pip is also not working. Its giving the same error

Comment: @RoadRunner Any non-trivial package has dependencies. Manual install of a package will lead `pip` to try to download dependencies — with the same network error.

Comment: @phd Then you need to download the other sub-dependencies, install them one by one, then you'll eventually get all the packages you need to do the manual install. Its a long process sometimes, but no other way if basic `pip install pandas` doesn't work.

Comment: @RoadRunner Hard to do manually, the tree of dependencies could be (and in case of `pandas` is) big, complex (version-dependent) and deep.